# Математический биллиард на Pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, информатика, логические-элементы

Недавно дали задание написать на PascalABC программу, реализующую решение логической задачи на переливание между сосудами методом математического биллиарда. Долго мучался, ничего не вышло.
Знает кто-то,  как создать такую?
Мое предположение: превратить параллелепипид биллиардного стола в прямоугольник и строить так.

Comment: покажите свои мучения

Comment: нечего показывать, я как гоголь психанул и удалил.  Всеравно она даже на 15% не написана была. Думал, тут помогут найти старт